# Why doesn't the -n switch print each line?

Tags: ruby, shell, command-line

I'm trying to pipe the output of a command like this:

```
some_command | ruby -ne "puts $_ if some_condition($_)"
```

However, all I see are empty lines. Where is each line being stored?

Comment: As an example, `ls | ruby -ne 'puts $_ if $_[0] == "r"'` works fine for me. Ensure that your `some_command` actually outputs to stdout.

Comment: Damn, I think bash screwed this up. I was using double quotes. Add an aswer, and I will mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work just fine. As an example, `ls | ruby -ne 'puts $_ if $_[0] == "r"'` prints just what I’d expect. You should ensure that your `some_command` is in fact outputting to stdout.